# Label for Inline Radio buttons bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was gold-plating the signup page by adding labels above each field when suddenly:

[image: part of signup page]

It worked fine but not with radio buttons. I'm relying on Bootstrap 3 and I think this can be solved without extra CSS but just with right nesting of Bootstrap classes. Right?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <label for="input-password">Password:</label>
           <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="input-password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <label for="input-confirm-password">Confirm Password:</label>
           <input name="confirm_password" id="input-confirm-password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required" />
      </div>
      </div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="input-address">Address:</label>
            <input name="address" id="input-address" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" />
       </div>
  </div>
  <label class="row">Gender:</label>
  <div class="form-group"> 
       <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                 <input name="gender" id="input-gender-male" value="Male" type="radio" />Male
             </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
             <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input name="gender" id="input-gender-female" value="Female" type="radio" />Female
             </label>
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
         <label>Account Type:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input name="account_type" id="input-type-student" value="Student" type="radio" />Student
                  </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="radio-inline">
                <input name="account_type" id="input-type-tutor" value="Tutor" type="radio" />Tutor
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I tried 2 different placement of the elements to resolve this issue as you can see but it didn't work.

I even tried putting a `div` around each set of the radio buttons and then gave a `label` for it but that didn't work either.

Comment: I pasted the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/miparnisari/3rpLqceL/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="input-type">Account Type *:</label>
        <div id="input-type" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input name="account_type" id="input-type-student" value="Student" type="radio" />Student
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input name="account_type" id="input-type-tutor" value="Tutor" type="radio" />Tutor
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do the same for the other radio buttons group.

Explanation: The `col-sm-6` of the outer `div` is now 100% and can be divided 50:50 by `col-sm-6` and `col-sm-6`